# Insert image into text and keep the text wrapping with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, text, word-wrap

I've just encountered a problem that my current (almost equal to 0) CSS knowledge cannot deal with. Here's the thing:

I have some text inside of a div element; this div element (let's call it a container) has a fixed width and dynamic height (no constraints). I'd like to put some text inside of the container; after the second word of the text, I'd like to put an image so that the whole things looks more or less like that:

```
+---------------------+
| I was [x] on my way |
| to the city in the  |
| sun                 |
+---------------------+
```

where [x] is the image. It's important for the second part of the text to wrap so that everything looks like in the above example.

The text in the container may vary; nevertheless I always know which part of the text goes before and which part of the text goes after the image.

How do I do that with CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the `<img>` tag in the middle of your text, things should behave like that by default, unless you override the image's `display` property. You may also want to experiment with the image's `vertical-align` property to make it line up nicely with the surrounding text.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Will it work with image that comes from a sprite?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "sprite". Any kind of image supported by the target browser will work - jpeg and gif are widely supported, and most browsers also accept png. Other image types are platform- and browser-dependent.

Comment: I was thinking of a sprite like that: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ . I'm not using explicit images, but div's with appropriate background setting.

Comment: I see. In that case, you'd have to explicitly set `display: inline-block` on the image div to make it behave as intended. This works on all standards-compliant browsers, but I think IE6 and maybe even 7 does not understand `inline-block`. `display: inline` probably won't work, because it doesn't give you enough control over the element's height.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're right, display: inline-block helped. Unfortunately, it needs a hack to work for IE7- (http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block.html) but the solution you provided is exactly what I needed.